# How to fill a list with information pulled from API

Tags: python, json, list, integer, openweathermap

I've been struggling to put values pulled from an API into a list.  Currently I can print each value individually, but can't seem to put the values in a list.  There are seven total values that I will be pulling online from the API.

```
    json_obj = urllib2.urlopen(url)

    data=json.load(json_obj)
    for item in data['list']:
            forecast=item['weather'][0]['id']
#           print(forecast)
            forecastlist=[]

            for item in forecast:
                    forecastlist.append(item)

    print(forecastlist)
```

I can't figure out how to take each individual forecast item and fill them into a list.  It should have seven total elements in it at the end of the list. The current error I am getting is:

```
TypeError:  'int' object is not iterable
```

Comment: When do you get the error?

Comment: I don't get why the nested loop. Wouldn't it be easier to just have forecastlist=[] before the first for loop, and then forecastles.append() immediately after the print?

Comment: When posting errors, it's helpful to include the *full* traceback, which has things like line numbers.

Comment: It's also helpful to not leave SO immediately after a question. People who take the trouble to answer sometimes need clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you running this:

```
for item in forecast: 
    forecastlist.append(item)
```

I think you can just do this and call it good:

```
forecastlist.append(forecast)
```

The error message is telling you that the `forecast` value is an integer, and I'm pretty sure that's the value that you're wanting to add to your list.

*Edit: it's also possible that your inner loop's `item` is stomping on the outer loop's `item`. You could try to rename one or the other of those. A traceback would be helpful though, along with the URL you're fetching.